# Calculate each customer cash expenditure and card expenditure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a little trouble figuring out solution to a sql query. 
The problem is as follows :

1) Transaction table

[image]

2) Customer table

[image]

3) Creditcard Table

[image]

**Problem: For each customer find their expenditure through each card and cash payment.**

What I have done is :

Applying an inner join over the three tables , I group by on the basis of cust_id and card_no and hence I get a result like below :

Query: `select cc.cust_id, name,cc.card_no,cc.card_type,sum(tran_sold_amt) from customer c join creditcard cc on c.cust_id=cc.cust_id join trans t on cc.card_no=t.card_no group by cc.cust_id,cc.card_no;`

[image]

*What I am unable to understand is **how do I recognise the cash payment is done by which customer and how do I aggregate them**. Is there some discrepancy in the question or am I making a mistake in understanding.*

Any help is really appreciated :)

- The problem stated exactly is : 
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and `JOIN` again.  Also, use just one database.  And tag your question with the one you are really using.

Comment: So you can join `customer` -> `credit_card` -> `transaction` to get the card payments. And you can then join the `transaction` table to itself again for cash payments. Although with the above data, that'll only work for one cash payment, but that is supported by the final example output you posted.

Comment: no customer to cash mapping ?

Comment: hey @RonakDhoot The customer to cash mapping is through the trans_id , ex for 2020 ID , you have one card and cash payment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for all the suggestions , I was able to solve by self joining the two tables:

```
Select 
    b.cust_id,
    b.name,
    payment,
    a.card_no,
    SUM(tran_sold_amt) from 
(SELECT
                c.cust_id as cust_id,
        c.name as name,
        CASE WHEN Payment_Method = "Cash" THEN "Cash" ELSE t.Card_type END AS payment,
        cc.card_no,
        tran_id,
        tran_sold_amt
    FROM
        trans t
    LEFT JOIN
        creditcard cc
    ON t.card_no = cc.card_no
    LEFT JOIN
        customer c
    ON cc.cust_id = c.cust_id) a 

    LEFT JOIN



(SELECT distinct tran_id, cust_id, name from (
SELECT
                c.cust_id as cust_id,
                tran_id,
                name
    FROM
        trans t
    LEFT JOIN
        creditcard cc
    ON t.card_no = cc.card_no
    LEFT JOIN
        customer c
    ON cc.cust_id = c.cust_id) where cust_id != 'null') b on a.tran_id = b.tran_id where b.cust_id != 'null' group by 1,2,3
```